# How to put POST data in an email form

Tags: php, forms

What I want to have, is a system that can send a user an email, using the POST data from the form so I have the correct email address to send an email to the user.

is this possible?

Please give a wide example... Ill provide an example:

and then. when the form is submitted. email the user with the mail function but include the "email" POST data.

Comment: Try did it by yourself

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail+form

Comment: use `phpmailer` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_POST['variable_name']` for getting email id  from form.

**Example**

```
$email_id=$_POST['email'];
```

after that, you can use `mail()` function for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it's possible you do `foreach` to get your $_POST datas and then use the mail() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
mail($to, //The rest of the stuff);
```